# How to find nodeRef with Alfresco Java API

Tags: java, api, alfresco

I would like to get the nodeRef of a stored node in alfresco. I have created a node with Alfresco java API and added a data object as a property of node in one method. Now I want to retrieve this data object from that nodeRef in second method. For this I am trying to get nodeRef of that stored node so I can get property of that object.

My code snippet is as below;

```
// Methos to set RegisterProperty dataobject in a node as a property of node 


public void registerProperty(RegisterProperty registerProperty) {

    registry.getAuthenticationService().authenticate("admin", "admin".toCharArray());

    /* Create Store */
    StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "myStoreProtocol" + GUID.generate());
    if (!nodeService.exists(storeRef)) {
        nodeService.createStore(storeRef.getProtocol(), storeRef.getIdentifier());
    }
    /* Get the root node from which to hang the next level of nodes */
    NodeRef rootNode = nodeService.getRootNode(storeRef);

    /*         Create child node              */
    ChildAssociationRef assocRef = nodeService.createNode(rootNode, ContentModel.ASSOC_CHILDREN, QName.createQName("vit-mrms", QName.createValidLocalName("myProperty-assocQName")), ContentModel.TYPE_CMOBJECT);
    NodeRef propertyRef = assocRef.getChildRef();

    /*  Store Serialized PropertyRegistration object as a node property  */
    QName myPropertyQname = QName.createQName("vit-mrms", registerProperty.getSurveyNo());
    nodeService.setProperty(propertyRef, myPropertyQname, registerProperty);
}


// Methos to get RegisterProperty dataobject from node.


public RegisterProperty getRegisterProperty(String surveyNo) {
    registry.getAuthenticationService().authenticate("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
    QName myPropertyQname = QName.createQName("vit-mrms", surveyNo);
    Serializable property = nodeService.getProperty(NodeRef, myPropertyQname);

// I want to retrieve this NodeRef 

    System.out.println("Store property in alfresco " + property.toString());
    return (RegisterProperty) property;
}

// Data object RegisterProperty is as follow,

public class RegisterProperty implements Serializable{

    private String ownerName;
    private String surveyNo;

    public String getOwnerName() {
        return ownerName;
    }

    public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
    }

    public String getSurveyNo() {
        return surveyNo;
    }
}
```

Please suggest a way to get NodeRef in getRegisterProperty() method so I can retrieve property from that node as a data object.

I tried  SearchService & nodeService to retrieve this node but didn't work for me.

---

Thank you so much Leonardo for quick reply :)

I didn't understand about property name as myprop in Lucene search query. what it shoud be in my case. While setting property to node I added Qname to nodeService.setProperty() method. is the myproperty same as Qname?

```
// while creating node set ptoperty
nodeService.setProperty(rootNodeRef, myQname, registerPropertyDataobject);

// my search query
ResultSet rs = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE, "@mynamespace\:myprop:\"" + whateverValue + "\"");
```

Also I am not getting syntax of licene search query.

> "@mynamespace:myprop:\"" + whateverValue + "\""